# How to apply a jquery zoom function to local Storage

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am using Ng-Storage. Right now I am using sessionStorage to remember a users selected object. I need to add localStorage to remember a users browsers window zoom level. I have a jquery function that zooms in and out but I do not know how to save it with the angular Storage. 
[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KfyJLmdWReqLKsIvs95a?p=preview)

```
var testapp = angular.module('testApp', ['ngStorage']);

 testapp.controller('controller1', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$sessionStorage','$localStorage', function($scope, $rootScope,$sessionStorage,$localStorage) {

$scope.selectedJob = $sessionStorage.$default($scope.jobs[1]);
$scope.selectJob = function(job) {
  angular.extend($scope.selectedJob, job);
};

 }]);


$(document).ready(function ($) {
var currFFZoom = 1;
var currIEZoom = 100;
$('#plusBtn').on('click', function () {
    var step = 2;
    currIEZoom += step;
    $('body').css('zoom', ' ' + currIEZoom + '%');
});
$('#minusBtn').on('click', function () {
    var step = 2;
    currIEZoom -= step;
    $('body').css('zoom', ' ' + currIEZoom + '%');
});

  });
```

Comment: get rid of the jQuery code and use an angular directive then you can inject the storage services in directive

Comment: any pointers on how to do that?

Comment: put an `ng-click` handler in link function of directive,use standard angular practices for injection of the service

Comment: I can setup a basic directive, but I am not sure I can translate this  $('body').css('zoom', ' ' + currIEZoom + '%'); to angular

Comment: angular has css method  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element